# How to make button share half the width of a dialog in android?

Tags: android, layout, dialog, line

i want to make the buttons take up half the width of the dialog each, thanks x3.
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:id="@+id/seperator_line" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Amount:" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@id/seperator_line" android:padding="10dp" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/deleteButton_dialog"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1" android:text="Delete" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cancelButton_dialog"
        android:text="Cancel" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/deleteButton_dialog"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code and a picture if you can. Without something more to go off of it is unlikely anyone will be able to tell you what is going on.

Comment: screw it lol il just do it with a textview instead

Comment: i changed the question can you help with that one?thanks x333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place them in a LinearLayout and then set the width to "fill_parent" and the layout_weight to "1".  Like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_below="@id/text1">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton_dialog"
            android:text="Delete" />
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton_dialog"
            android:text="Cancel"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: lol cheers but when i put this linear layout under my relative layout all the content of the whole dialog dissapears:(

Comment: You'll have to play around with the wrapping XML, but if you posted the new layout, I could try to help